# Can't access external sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

i have just configured a new sharepoint 2010 web application, but i can't seem to access the site collection from the internet.

i have extended the web application and when i try to access the site (portal.mydomain.net), it asks me for credentials, but once i enter them, i get an error page (internet explorer cannot display the webpage).

internally, the site collection works fine on port 8080, but i have set up a extender that uses port 80, so i just have to enter portal.mydomain.com to get access (that's what i want to do anyway).

i have set up port forwarding on my router to forward external domain (portal.mydomain.net) port 80 to internal ip and port 8080, but not sure if this is the correct setup.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,

shannon

Answer (score 1):

I believe the configuration as explained mixes concepts. Extending a SharePoint Web Application practically means creating a new IIS Web Site, with its own Host-headers also (as described) so forwarding the calls to 8080 is not the way is meant to function (it will work if properly configured for header replacement, but is tricky). You simply would need to "Publish" in your reverse-proxy the "Extended" URL of the SharePoint, while keeping the same Headers (for simplicity).

Alternatively, you could forget about extending your web application and simply use AAM with the target URL and than use you forwarder to send all requests coming for that address to the 8080 version.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some like ISA server that will change the headers, I'm not sure it will work as you expect.  Have you tried adding portal.mydomain.com:80 as an alternate access mapping?

Comment: when i try to specifically add the port 80, it automatically removes it.  i assume because it assumes port 80 if no port is specified.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to see what is being returned to your browser?

Comment: will look into it and post results...  thanks for the help.